# Reasons to invest in 401k vs pay off loan in 1 year?

Tags: united-states, investing, 401k, retirement, debt-reduction

I have ~$70k across 401k and Roth IRA. I have federal student loan at $17k with 3.8%. Thus, my NW is $53k.

If I choose to invest $19k into my 401k and assume the average rate of return of 7%, my 401k grows to $95k. My student loan goes up to $17.6k with the 3.8% interest. That puts my NW at $77.4k.

If I choose to pay off my loan in one year, my 401k grows to $75k and that becomes my NW.

401k is better for my NW, but I still have the burden of the loan. What would make investing into my 401k the better option other than NW?

Comment: Life is full of risk, don't bet on uncertain gain.  This is not risk aversion, because not everyone has a father called Fred Trump.

Comment: Based on your question it seems that the student loan payment is optional/ Is that a true assumption?

Comment: How much of your loan can you afford to pay if you max out the 401k? (What's the total you can afford per year: 401k contributions plus student loan payments?)

Answer (score 6):

> What would make investing into my 401k the better option other than NW?

Company match.  Eliminating all 401(k) contribs means no company match, and that's a pay cut, which naturally is Unwise.

More important is the foolishly binary thinking embedded in your statement:

> If I choose to invest $19k into my 401k

Who mandates that you must fully contribute into your 401(k)?

Contributing -- for example -- $8500 to your 401(k) and $8500 against your student loans kills two birds with 17,000 stones instead of one bird.  Especially with the company match.

And your SL debt is gone in just two years.

Answer (score 0):

> If I choose to invest $19k into my 401k and assume the average rate of return of 7%,

And here we go. Assuming a company match for the 19000 your first year investment is an average of 107% (!). Beat that. See, your 19000 get matched with ANOTHER 19000 by the company and THEN you make 7% (also on the match? not sure). Also there is this thing about pre and post deductions ;) Anyone can go in here? is a 401k pre-tax pre-deductions? Not american here.

Comment: Just checked: 401k is actually tax deferred, so the 190 are taken BEFORE calcualting your tax. Another gain compared to repaying the student loan.

Comment: The match generally is not a 100% match. Usually it has a limit of g% of salary, but the rules depend on the company. Also 401(k) comes in two flavors: traditional pre-tax, and Roth post-tax.

Comment: "Generally" is understating it. I would love to see a counterexample to "The match is *never* (or even rarely) 100%."

Comment: @chepner My last employer matched 100% of my contributions up to 15% of my gross pay. Other companies in that industry had 100% matches, but only up to 6-10% of pay.

Comment: @TomTom by your math it would be a 114% match because both the money you contribute and the money your company contributes is placed in the stock market. so both get a 7% increase.

Comment: @DStanley OK, I guess I should have been more explicit and said "100% of *all* contributions". (I don't recall at the moment if my own match is 50% or 100% of some cap.)

Comment: @chepner But it was a 100% match of all of my contributions. My contributions, though, were limited to a % of my salary. I put in the IRS max, which was about 14% of my salary, and the company matched it 100%.

Comment: @DStanley Yours, yes. The OP is implying you can get a full match on $19,000. (Which is technically possible, if you make in the neighborhood of $200-$300k, but people with those salaries generally aren't trying to optimize the repayment of $17k in student loans.)

Comment: We can only work with the numbers people give, regardless how much sense they make ;)

Comment: @chepner I'm just saying it's _possible_ - and you did ask for a counterexample :)

Comment: @TomTom the question doesn't indicate a match at all and your answer assumes 100% match on the IRS max.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *mathematically*, **on average** investing in equities in your 401(k) will put you ahead, but unless you can get a full match on the 19% (which is very rare), then the gain isn't life-changing (maybe an extra $5-10k depending on the amount and limit of the match). Plus, if you're young, you still have plenty of time to make up for the lost match, and with no student loan burden, you can invest *even more* in the future!

The main differentiator is *risk*. You and I both admit that *on average* equities return more, but the range is massive. in any given year, equities can return anywhere from -30% in crashes to +40% (which is usually a *recovery* from a crash). We've seen relatively stable growth for the last several years, which might continue, or might not. If you are comfortable with that type of risk and aren't adding any *more* debt, then you will probably be OK letting the loans drag out a little bit.

I'm usually in the minority on these questions, but I've experienced firsthand the liberation of getting rid of debt (especially student loan debt) even before 401(k) matches. Yes, that match is hard to leave on the table, but having that debt gone opens up many more options for investment. Plus you're only losing the match for *one year*. I'll take that versus dragging out student loans for several years.

All that to say that there's no *bad* answer here. Either option sets you up for financial security in the future, so do whichever gives you more satisfaction/peace/stability now.